# How to find the following limit as x approaches zero by using Taylor series (or alternative means other than L'Hopital's rule)

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

The limit in question is:

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x  \sin x - x(x+1)}{x^3}$$

The answer is supposedly $1/3$, and it is quite simple to find the limit using L'Hopital's rule. However, we are only permitted to use Taylor series formulas in class for solving this type of questions, and, by applying Taylor series to $e^x$ and $\sin x$, I don't seem to be able to get anything that can cancel with $x^3$, so I always end up getting

$$\frac{1}{x^n}$$

where $n$ is $1,2$ or $3$, and since $x$ approaches $0$, this renders the limit unsolvable (or incorrect) as I get multiple infinite values adding and subtracting one another.

I would be grateful if anyone could help me out with this.

Comment: Just add and subtract $xe^x$ in numerator and split as $\frac{\sin x-x} {x^3}\cdot e^x+\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$ and your job is done by using Taylor series. You should note that it is always better to do some algebraic simplification so that one can avoid multiplication / division / composition of Taylor series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the denominator is $x^3$, you have to at least expand the exponential and the sine function up to order three. Consider this:

$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^3)$$

$$\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^3)$$

Thence

$$e^x \sin(x) = \left(1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^3)\right)\left(x - \frac{x^3}{6} + o(x^3)\right) = x + x^2 - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^3}{2} + o(x^3)$$

That is

$$e^x \sin(x) = x + x^2 + \frac{x^3}{3} + o(x^3)$$

Where we have trashed terms of order higher than $x^3$.

Then we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x + x^2 + \frac{x^3}{3} + o(x^3) - x^2 - x}{x^3} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{x^3}{3} + o(x^3)}{x^3} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{3} + \underbrace{\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{o(x^3)}{x^3}}_{\to 0} = \frac{1}{3}$$